# The Health proposal is in commitment phase

Tags: discussion

Since health and nutrition are closely related to physical fitness, some might be interested in the  [Health proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=3bnJk5Umd0S9V8Fef65Ucg2), which is now in commitment phase.

Comment: Thanks, become a supporter/contrib/whatever I did.

Comment: This Health SE didn't turn out well: much content is deleted, many unanswered questions, most experts don't stay on the website due to the ambiance, http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/332/is-health-se-sick, etc.